# Push Notifications on iPhone App

Tags: iphone, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have successfully implemented push notifications to my app. The next step is, if the user receives a notification about this certain document, he/ she clicks it and it brings them to this document.

At the moment, I can receive the notification, but it only brings me to the app.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear with your question. But you should handle push notifications in the following methods,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
//Handle here
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
 NSDictionary *tmpDic = [launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
if (tmpDic != nil) {
        //Handle here also
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, my question is: When a user receives the push notification and taps on it, it would then bring them to the relevant document/ uiview. At the moment, when the user tabs on the notification, it only brings them to the application.

Comment: @Honda: You have to send some info in the push notification as a NSDictionary and based on that value for key move to the particular uiview

Comment: Right. Sounds like complicated stuff. :/. Is there some documentation on this? Thanks.